# Click btn to open a new page in which there is a link

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am currently studying Google app engine and Kay framework (created based on Django and Jinja2).

Here is my app-> http://cayotkanawa.appspot.com/display
You can see there are some links in the last columns.
I want to replace them with buttons. If I click on a button, a new page will be open and there is link and information in that page.

Here is the code of the html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Top Page - myapp</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% if displaygolf %}
  <div id="displaygolf">
      <table border="1">
          <tr>
              <td>No</td>
              <td>ゴフル場名</td>
              <td>名義変換料</td>
              <td>URL</td>
          </tr>
          {% for golfelement in displaygolf %}
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>{{ golfelement.golfname }}</td>
              <td>{{ golfelement.changenamefee }}</td>
              <td>
                  <a href="{{golfelement.url_1net}}">1net | </a> 
                  <a href={{golfelement.url_golfagora}}>Golfagora | </a> 
                  <a href={{golfelement.url_juchi}}>Juchi</a> 

              </td>

          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      </table>

  </div>
    {% endif %}



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

nothing to do with Django here. Set your link tag to target="_blank"

```
<a href="{{golfelement.url_1net}}" target="_blank" >1net | </a> 
<a href={{golfelement.url_golfagora}} target="_blank" >Golfagora | </a> 
<a href={{golfelement.url_juchi}} target="_blank" >Juchi</a>
```

Comment: this will open a new page, but i does not satisfy my need. I need to open a new page, there is the {{golfelement.url_1net}} in that page.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to accomplish having a button element act as a link is this:

```
<form action="http://example.org" method="GET">
       <button>Link</button>
</form>
```

This validates, but I don't think it is a very nice solution to what you are looking for. Instead, I suggest looking in to using CSS to style the `<a>` tags to look like buttons.

You can see an example in the Twitter Bootstrap framework section on [buttons](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons). They have styled `<a>` and `<button>` tags to look the same, this way all you would have to do is apply the CSS classes to your links if you were to use Bootstrap:

```
<a href="{{golfelement.url_1net}}" class="btn">1net | </a> 
<a href={{golfelement.url_golfagora}} class="btn">Golfagora | </a> 
<a href={{golfelement.url_juchi}} class="btn">Juchi</a>
```

The concept is the same if you were to make your own CSS classes, or use another framework.

This question actually has to do with HTML and CSS, it is independent of the other technologies you are using.